# Can one use forcing as a step to prove the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Can one use forcing (perhaps at the expense of using larger ultrafilters) to prove the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem? My idea is to use an ultrafilter $U$ on a set $I$ such that if $M=V^{I}/U$, then $M$ has some generic ultrafilter $G$ such that the desired structures are isomorphic by an isomorphism in $M[G]$ and therefore the structures are isomorphic.

Suppose that $\kappa$ is a cardinal. Let $I$ be an index set. Suppose furthermore that $\mathcal{A}_{i}$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{B}_{i}$ and $|\mathcal{A}_{i}|<\kappa,|\mathcal{B}_{i}|<\kappa$ for each $i\in I$. Then I hope the following strategy could be used to obtain an ultrafilter $U$ where $\prod_{I\in I}\mathcal{A}_{i}/U\simeq\prod_{I\in I}\mathcal{B}_{i}/U$.

Step 1: Find a partition $P$ of $I$ along with ultrafilters $U_{R}$ on $R$ for each $R\in P$ such that $\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{A}_{i}/U_{R}$ and $\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{B}_{i}/U_{R}$ satisfy the same $\mathcal{L}_{\omega,\infty}$ formulas. Could one use the saturation
of the ultraproducts to show that the ultraproducts are $\mathcal{L}_{\omega,\infty}$-elementarily equivalent?

Step 2: Force. Find an ultrafilter $U$ on $P$ along with a generic ultrafilter $G\subseteq p\subseteq M=V^{P}/U$ where $M[G]$ collapses the cardinality
of each $\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{A}_{i}/U_{R}$ and $\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{B}_{i}/U_{R}$ to $\omega$. In this case, 
$\prod_{R\in P}(\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{A}_{i}/U_{R})/U$ and $\prod_{R\in P}(\prod_{i\in R}\mathcal{B}_{i}/U_{R})/U$ will both become isomorphic in $M[G]$ and therefore isomorphic in $V$.

Both step 1 and step 2 are special cases of the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem. Can one show that step 1 or step 2 requires the full power of the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Where's Noah Schweber? This question seems right up his alley.